# using redis in node.js

Tags: node.js, redis

I recently wanted to process some large data in nodejs and then put them into mongodb, at first I tried to process data in memory (javascript arrays),but when I decide to use node cluster, I figured out that by using node cluster it is not good way to use cache object. however, it seems impractical solution to store data in arrays even for short time. I think it would be better to store it in some memory databases such as redis.

so my first question is whether I can use redis via node cluster or not? and whether redis is the best solution or not?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Answer to q1: yes, you can use redis via the node cluster. Answer to q2: depends on too many factors. Other than that, your intentions are rather unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the cluster module, an external data store is by far the simplest way of sharing state. Think of each worker as an individual client accessing the data store. Redis happens to be perfectly fit for the job, but the same can be said for just about any database. For short term storage, redis and memcached are both popular solutions. For arrays, redis beats memcached because it has an array like type that you can [push to and pop from](http://redis.io/commands#list).

An extremely popular library for Node.js connecting to redis is [node-redis](https://npmjs.org/package/redis). I've personally used it and highly recommend the API.